# Flutter App is requesting permissions even after deleting Permission Handler Plugin

Tags: flutter, permissions

This is how I requested permissions initially.

```
Map <Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses =
await [Permission.storage, Permission.camera, ].request();
```

I even commented permissions from AndroidManifest.xml

```
<!--
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
-->
```

I also invalidated cache and used Flutter Clean after uninstalling the app.
The result is same on physical device and emulator.

Here's Flutter Doctor's result:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.836], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.17.1 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision f7a6a7906b (4 weeks ago), 2020-05-12 18:39:00 -0700
    • Engine revision 6bc433c6b6
    • Dart version 2.8.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Achal\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.8052
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.3)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3
    • Flutter plugin version 45.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.6911.31

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Redmi Note 7 Pro • f55ccaf1 • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

check if the app is uninstalled properly

Type this in terminal/cmd

adb uninstall your_package_name

Comment: It says ```'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.```